# Extraction and seperate texts from PPT slides using ApachePOI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to extract all text from PPTS and segregate them using paragraphs and line break tags.

```
NPOIFSFileSystem poifs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(inputStream);
PowerPointExtractor extractor = new PowerPointExtractor(poifs);
StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(extractor2.getText()));

String line = null;
while ((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.trim().length() > 2) {
        line = line.replaceAll("  ", "<br />");
        line = line.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
        line = Normalizer.normalize(line, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        SB.append("<p>").append(line).append("</p>\r\n");
    }
}
System.out.println(SB.toString());
```

However, let's say that in a particular slide that contains a table with multiple cells that looks like this:

[image: Input]

Using the code above, the output becomes like this

[image: Output]

Is there a way to properly go through each slide then extract and separate the text according to their containers?

Example

```
<p>IBM IBM IBM MS IBM MS</p> 

will become 

<p>IBM</p><p>IBM</p><p>IBM</p><p>MS</p><p>IBM</p><p>MS</p>
```

Comment: Why not access the slide object directly, and get text from elements, rather than the easy-but-simplistic text extractor?

Comment: Just looking into the documentation of ApachePOI. I just discovered HSLFGroupShape, implemented it and did the trick. Will HSLFTextShape and HSLFGroupShape be enough to grab all the text? I looked into the output and it seemed to get all the texts. Need to double check.

Comment: Some shapes can have other shapes, so you might need a bit or recursion in places. [Have a read of the source code of PowerPointExtractor](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/scratchpad/src/org/apache/poi/hslf/extractor/PowerPointExtractor.java) to see what's needed!